# PHP uma Tabela chama outra Tabela dinâmica

Tags: php

Estou precisando que quando o usuário selecionar um item combo que o próximo combo seja carregado com os dados relacionados a ao primeiro.

Já fiz isso:

```
    <?php
        session_start();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>PHP form select box example</title>
        </head>

        <body>

        <?php
            $selected='';
            function get_options($select)
            {
                $countries=array ('United States'=>1,'United Kingdom'=>2,'France'=>3,'Mexico'=>4,'Russia'=>5,'Japan'=>6);
                $options='';
                while(list($k,$v)=each($countries))
                {
                    if($select==$v)
                    {
                        $options.='<option value="'.$v.'" selected>'.$k.'</option>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $options.='<option value="'.$v.'">'.$k.'</option>';
                    }
                }
                return $options;
            }
            if(isset($_POST['countries']))
            {
                $selected= $_POST['countries'];
                $_SESSION['pais'] = $selected;  
            }

            function get_cidade()
            {
                if(isset($_SESSION['pais'])){
                $pais = $_SESSION['pais'];
                $options2='';

                if($pais==1)
                {
                    $options2.="<option value='New York' selected>New York</option>\n";
                    $options2.="<option value='San Francisco'>San Franciso</option>\n";
                    $options2.="<option value='Washington'>Washington</option>\n";
                }
                if($pais==2)
                {
                    $options2.="<option value='London'>London</option>";
                    $options2.="<option value='Manchester'>Manchester</option>";
                    $options2.="<option value='Edimburgo'>Edimburgo</option>";
                }
                if($pais==3)
                {
                    $options2.="<option value='Paris'>Paris</option>";
                    $options2.="<option value='Lyon'>Lyon</option>";
                    $options2.="<option value='Marselha'>Marselha</option>";
                }
                if($pais==4)
                {
                    $options2.="<option value='Cuidad del Mexico'>Cuidad del Mexico</option>";
                    $options2.="<option value='Guadalajara'>Guadalajara</option>";
                    $options2.="<option value='Monterrei'>Monterrei</option>";
                }
                if($pais==5)
                {
                    $options2.="<option value='Moscou'>Moscou</option>";
                    $options2.="<option value='Samara'>Samara</option>";
                    $options2.="<option value='Kaluga'>Kaluga</option>";
                }
                if($pais==6)
                {
                    $options2.="<option value='Toquio'>Toquio</option>";
                    $options2.="<option value='Quioto'>Quioto</option>";
                    $options2.="<option value='Hiroshima'>Hiroshima</option>";
                }

                return $options2;
                }
            }
        ?>
        <form name="frm1" action="testetabelas7.php" method="post">
            <form name="fcountries" id="frm2" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                <label for='formCountries[]'>Select the countries that you have visited:</label><br>
                <select name="countries" onchange="form.submit();" >
                    <?php echo get_options($selected); ?>
                </select><br>
            </form>
            <p>Cidade</p>
            <form name="cities" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                <select name="cidade">
                    <?php echo get_cidade(); ?>
                </select> 
            </form>
            <input form="frm1" type="submit" value="Gravar" >
        </form>


        </body>
    </html>
```

O problema está que quando mudo a opção o submit não está sendo para o submit do form interno, mas para o form externo.

Já tentei this.form.submit()

Eu não sei como chamar dar submit no form interno.

O arquivo testetabelas7.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>PHP form select box example</title>
        </head>

        <body>

        <?php
            $co = $_POST['countries'];
            $cy = $_POST['cidade'];
            echo '<p>'.$co.'</p>';  
            echo '<p>'.$cy.'</p>';  
        ?>  

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sugiro que tenha apenas um form e use ajax para inserir as opções do select

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo simples e prático? Estou evitando ao máximo javascript, pois a antiga versão disso estava muito lenta e pesada (100% java) e estamos migrando para PHP que por enquanto se mostrou muitas vezes mais rápido.

Comment: Lembre-se que o Javascript vai tirar toda a carga do servidor e tráfego de rede, portanto tente verificar o que considera uma aplicação "pesada"... É pesada para o servidor ou cliente? Se for para usar Ajax tente usar como base esse exemplo: https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-how-to-make-dependent-dropdown-list-using-jquery-ajaxexample.html

Comment: JavaScript e Java são coisas bem diferentes

Comment: Pesado... e lento...os remendos inviabilizaram o projeto.... sei que há a polêmica... mas coisas simples estavam levando de 3 a 5 minutos para abrir...

Comment: Fernando, muito bom, mas por isso mesmo que evito os "javas" tem que usar as bibliotecas:  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>..... isso não é muito agradável, pois tem gente que vai usar no celular.... quanto menos treco melhor e mais rápido.... mas vou tentar...obrigado por enquanto... é que todos acham que seja impossível no PHP... e estou quase lá

Comment: As bibliotecas javascript (no exemplo dado o jquery) são incluídas para dar suporte às requisições assíncronas com o servidor. Nesse exemplo ele usou a biblioteca externa para deixar mais simples, mas você pode ter essa biblioteca dentro do seu próprio projeto. O css externo (bootstrap) também foi colocado só como exemplo e nem precisa ser usado ou pode ser importado no seu projeto também,

Answer (score 1):

Se você não tiver muitos registros você poderá fazer da forma que coloco abaixo. Senão você terá que fazer um formulário com combobox dinâmicos usando Ajax ou algo semelhante.

```
<script>
function pais_onchange(){
    var selPaisValue = document.getElementById("pais").value;
    var selCidade = document.getElementById("cidade");

    for(var i=selCidade.options.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        selCidade.remove(i);
    }

    if(selPaisValue=="1"){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = "A1";
        option.value="A1";
        selCidade.add(option);
        option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = "B1";
        option.value="B1";
        selCidade.add(option);
    }
    else if(selPaisValue=="2"){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = "A2";
        option.value="A2";
        selCidade.add(option);
        option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = "B2";
        option.value="B2";
        selCidade.add(option);
    }
}
</script>

Pais: 
<select id="pais" name="pais" onchange="pais_onchange();">
<option value="S" selected="selected">-Escolha o País-</option>
<option value="1">País 1</option>
<option value="2">País 2</option>
</select>

<br />
Cidade: 
<select name="cidade" id="cidade">
</select>
```

Pelo código indicado me parecem ser poucas opções de países e cidades, por isso resolvi já partir para essa solução simplificada.

Comment: Ótimo, código bem bom mesmo, o mais limpo que vi, agora se eu for pegar os dados do MySQL para criar um array? E tenho outra conexão o PostgreSQL.

Comment: Se for pegar da BD para colocar no javascript basta fazer dois loops repetindo a estrutura colocada. Faz um loop nos países e repete o if(selPaisValue=="$cod_pais") ( ...) , quando funcionar bem, dentro desse loop faz um segundo loop que cria as options das cidades: var option (...) até selCidade.add(option);

Comment: observações: veja que a partir do segundo IF de país inserir um ELSE antes dos próximos IF (não é obrigatório, mas uma boa prática até para manter o código mais rápido). também a partir do primeiro option não é preciso declarar novamente a variável.

Comment: Assim eu volto a estaca zero.... tudo java... e isso a empresa não quer... a conexão com MySQL e PostgreSQL do PHP é super simples... me desculpem... por isso coloquei no PHP e não no grupo Java

Comment: Não estamos falando de Java e sim Javascript que são coisas totalmente diferentes. Você não vai ter opção de fazer essa ação sem recarregar a página só utilizando PHP, sem Javascript (que é o que roda no cliente para comunicar com o servidor ou faz o controle diretamente no cliente).

Comment: O não é possível, eu já tenho de vários sites.... e consegui chegar a um bom denominador.. o cara acima roda chamando um ao outro.. testei com banco de dados e tudo... só preciso agora acerta o evento ONCHANGE... se conseguir isso está pronto...